# Query to Add Invoice to table by checking each line attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Invoice
========
InvoiceID
LineID
ItemID
AmountInc
MenuPrice

#TempTable
========
InvoiceID
AmountInc (will have Sum(AmountInc))
```

I want to build a table which derived the data from Invoice table as per above columns.

The Invoice will need to have at least one line of item with MenuPrice = Yes in order to be added to the temp table, example:

```
> InvoiceTable
> InvoiceID | LineID | ItemID | AmountInc | MenuPrice
  0001      | 1      | A001   | 10        | Yes
  0001      | 2      | A002   | 20        | No
  0002      | 1      | A001   | 10        | No
  0002      | 2      | A003   | 15        | No
  0002      | 3      | A001   | 10        | No
  0003      | 1      | A003   | 15        | Yes
  0003      | 2      | A004   | 25        | Yes
```

Results will be:

```
#TempTable
> InvoiceID | AmountInc
  0001      | 30        
  0003      | 15
```

Or this one if possible:

```
#TempTable
> InvoiceID | AmountInc | MenuPrice
  0001      | 30        | Mixed
  0002      | 35        | No
  0003      | 40        | Yes
```

What's the best way to write this?

Comment: Why does `InvoiceID` `0003` have a sum of 15, when `0001` appears to have the sum of all records?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, fixed now and I hope it give you better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(InvoiceID INT, LineID INT,ItemID VARCHAR(10),AmountInc INT,MenuPrice VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (0001,1,'A001',10,'Yes')
,(0001,2,'A002',20,'No')
,(0002,1,'A001',10,'No')
,(0002,2,'A003',15,'No')
,(0002,3,'A001',10,'No')
,(0003,1,'A003',15,'Yes')
,(0003,2,'A004',25,'Yes');
```

--The query will use a cte first to find all values for `InvoiceID` with at least one `Yes`, then this list of valid IDs will be used to `INNER JOIN` the list.

```
WITH AllYes AS
(
    SELECT InvoiceID
    FROM @tbl
    WHERE MenuPrice='Yes'
    GROUP BY InvoiceID
)
SELECT t.InvoiceID,SUM(t.AmountInc) AS SumAount
FROM @tbl t
INNER JOIN AllYes y ON t.InvoiceID=y.InvoiceID
GROUP BY t.InvoiceID;
```

The result

```
InvoiceID   SumAount
1           30
3           40
```

And this query would bring back your alternative expected result:

```
SELECT t.InvoiceID
      ,SUM(t.AmountInc) AS SumAmount
      ,A.YesExists
      ,A.NoExists
      ,CASE WHEN YesExists+NoExists=2 THEN 'Mixed' ELSE
            CASE WHEN NoExists=1 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END 
       END AS InvStatus  
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl t1 WHERE t1.InvoiceID=t.InvoiceID AND MenuPrice='Yes') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS YesExists
                  ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl t1 WHERE t1.InvoiceID=t.InvoiceID AND MenuPrice='No') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NoExists ) A
GROUP BY t.InvoiceID,A.YesExists,A.NoExists;
```

Comment: Hi @Shnugo , Thanks for the answer and it works like a charm! I have modified the query a bit for my need which still works based on your supplied code. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below

```
With TempTable As
(
    Select InvoiceID, Sum(AmountInc) AmountInc, MenuPrice From InvoiceTable 
    Group By InvoiceID, MenuPrice
)
Select InvoiceID, Sum(AmountInc) AmountInc, 
Case When Count(*) > 1 then 'Mixed' Else Max(MenuPrice) End MenuPrice
From TempTable Group By InvoiceID
```